# How to run a AppleScript with thread when a button pressed?

Tags: xcode, applescript, nsthread, applescript-objc

I have created a NSthread in main.m, but what I want is to execute a section of AppleScript in the AppDelegate.applescript with thread when I press a button, the AppleScript like:

```
on run1_(sender)
    repeat
        say (current date) as string
    end repeat
end run1_
```

so I can continue to press other buttons, such as a button to stop the running AppleScript above.

Comment: applescript is always executed on the main thread

Comment: That's true for AppleScript-ObjC. AppleScripts executed via OSA APIs can run on background threads, but you need to create a new component instance per-thread, which means using the public but undocumented `OSAKit` framework. If the arguments are simple strings, I'd just call `osascript` via `NSTask` as that's non-blocking. The one catch is you'll need to wrap it in some ObjC code if you want its result code as ASOC doesn't support ObjC blocks, which `NSTask` uses to notify your app when the subprocess has finished. TBH ASOC has a low ceiling for app development; if you want more, learn Swift.